# track changes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have eclipse installed on a local computer, and am working on a project by myself.  No one else is collaborating on the coding, I am doing it all myself.

Sometimes, I get ambiguous error messages in my spring mvc app when I run it on tomcat server using eclipse's run as...run on server command.  For example, there is sometimes NO stack trace.  In those cases, I would like to at least be able to see when each file in the app was last saved, so that I can try to figure out what I changed since the last time the app ran successfully.  Ideally, I would like to also be able to see what changes I made to specific files.

Can anyone show me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has Local History feature: try **Team > Show Local History** from context menu.
But I recommend you to use some version control system (svn, git) even if you work on your project alone.

Comment: when I right click on my project's root folder and select `Team` from the context menu, there is no option for `Show Local History`.  Is there somewhere else I should look?  I am using eclipse kepler for spring mvc project with maven.  I think it is a dynamic web project in eclipse.  Not sure if the eclipse view is effecting things.